# regex for java split

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split data from file which have the following format: 
{[(1;1;2),(5;1;2),(5;1;1)],[(1;3;2),(5;3;2),(5;1;2)]}

And here is my Java method for that:

```
public void createFromFile(String filename) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        s = s.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");
        ArrayList<Surface> sf = new ArrayList<Surface>();
        for(String s1: s.split("\\["))
        { // <== not splitting here
            ArrayList<Point> tp = new ArrayList<Point>();
            for(String s2: s1.split("\\("))
            { // <== here neither
                String[] s3 = s2.split(";");
                tp.add(new Point(Double.valueOf(s3[0]),Double.valueOf(s3[1]),Double.valueOf(s3[2])));
            }
            sf.add(new Surface((Point[]) tp.toArray()));
        }
        convShape.add(new Body((Surface[])sf.toArray()));   
    }
}
```

why does `s.split("\\[")` and `s.split("\\(")` do not split s?

Comment: sorry, I'll edit it right now.

Comment: So you want all the numbers between brackets

Comment: Yes, but want them grouped by "("")" too, and then by "[""]", and finally by "{""}"

Comment: Ughh - what a horrible way to implement a parser ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that should work. As far as your current code is concerned, it should correctly split it.

But, given that you just want the `numbers` inside the brackets. You don't need a `split` here. You are making your job tough. You should better use `Pattern` and `Matcher` class, to find everything in between `(` and `)`. You can use the below code for your help: -

```
    String str = "{[(1;1;2),(5;1;2),(5;1;1)],[(1;3;2),(5;3;2),(5;1;2)]}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(\\d;\\d;\\d\\),?){3}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println("Polygon Coordinates: ");
        String[] coordinates = matcher.group(0).split(",");

        for (String point: coordinates) {
            System.out.println("Coordinate " + (i++) + ": " + point);

            point = point.replace("\\(", "").replace("\\)", "");
            String[] s3 = point.split(";");
            tp.add(new Point(Double.valueOf(s3[0]), Double.valueOf(s3[1]),
                             Double.valueOf(s3[2])));

        }

        sf.add(new Surface((Point[]) tp.toArray()));
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
Polygon Coordinates: 
Coordinate 1: (1;1;2)
Coordinate 2: (5;1;2)
Coordinate 3: (5;1;1)

Polygon Coordinates: 
Coordinate 1: (1;3;2)
Coordinate 2: (5;3;2)
Coordinate 3: (5;1;2)
```

**Explanation**: -

- `(\\(\\d;\\d;\\d\\),?){3}` - This matches `3 groups` of `3 integers` separated by a `;` inside `brackets`, with `groups` separated by `comma(,)`. Then it captures the complete match.
- `matcher.find()` - Finds everything from the string, that matches the above pattern.
- `matcher.group(0)` - Gets the complete match.
- Split the complete match on `comma(,)` to get individual coordinates
- If you want to match `double` or `integer` values separated by `;`, you would need to change the `Regex` a little bit. That I leave to you.
- See [Pattern class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details on various `quantifiers`. `{3}` in the above regex is one of the quantifiers.

Comment: Close enough! but it doesn't group (1;1;2) (5;1;2) (5;1;1). (x;y;z) are the coordinate of some top of a polygon, so I really need them grouped :)

Comment: @mhfff32. Ok. I'll change the regex.

Comment: @mhfff32. Changed Regexp. You can try that.

Comment: +1, very clean attempt (especially compared to the code in the answer)

Comment: @Downvoter can you please comment to make your downvote more meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it smells like JSON, but if you want to use split, then

- to get groups find all matches of `/[\\d;]+/`
- to get numbers from the groups, use split using `";"`

---

#### Demo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String str = "{[(1;1;2),(5;1;2),(5;1;1)],[(1;3;2),(5;3;2),(5;1;2)]}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d;]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        String[] numbers = matcher.group(0).split(";");
        int i = 1;
        for (String number: numbers) {
            System.out.println("Parameter #" + i + ": " + number);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
  }
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
1;1;2
Parameter #1: 1
Parameter #2: 1
Parameter #3: 2

5;1;2
Parameter #1: 5
Parameter #2: 1
Parameter #3: 2

5;1;1
Parameter #1: 5
Parameter #2: 1
Parameter #3: 1

1;3;2
Parameter #1: 1
Parameter #2: 3
Parameter #3: 2

5;3;2
Parameter #1: 5
Parameter #2: 3
Parameter #3: 2

5;1;2
Parameter #1: 5
Parameter #2: 1
Parameter #3: 2
```

Test this demo [**here**](http://ideone.com/NxKFwg).

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to match the required data in groups

```
Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{).*?(?<=\\})").matcher(yourInput);
while(mather1.find())
{
    Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])").matcher(matcher1.Group());
    while (matcher2.find()) 
    {
        Matcher matcher3 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+);(\\d+);(\\d+)").matcher(matcher2.Group());
    while (matcher3.find()) 
    {

        tp.add(new Point(Double.valueOf(matcher3.Group(1),Double.valueOf(matcher3.Group(2)),Double.valueOf(matcher3.Group(3))));
    }
       sf.add(new Surface((Point[]) tp.toArray()));  
    }
convShape.add(new Body((Surface[])sf.toArray()));   
}
```